How to use an iPad as an external MIDI keyboard for the Mac?
I'm looking for an app for iPadOS that would connect via Bluetooth (or cable if needed) to a Mac and work as a MIDI keyboard.
The goal is to use it to input notes in a notation program such as Dorico, Sibelius, Finale, Musescore, ...
When travelling, I cannot bring my big keyboard with me, so this would greatly help.
Is there any such app?
